# Xamarin Forms: StackLayout with rounded corners

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am developing an app using Xamarin Forms PCL. I need a StackLayout with rounded corners. I have tried frame as well for rounded corner container but there is no corner radius property available for it. I cannot find renderers for iOS,Android,UWP,Windows 8.1.

Please can any one suggest me how to achieve StackLayout with rounded corners along with corner radius property for all the platforms.
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/RoundedBoxView

Comment: @Depechie i dont need boxview  i want stacklayout so that i can put elements into it

Comment: Still can put stuff on top of the box view

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57473/how-can-i-customize-the-border-of-stack-layout

Comment: @Depechie But how? I have tried adding elements to boxview but that didn't work

Comment: Just put things in same grid cell

Comment: @Depechie ok box view first then elements that I want on top of it.

Answer (score 82):

You can use Frame and put StackLayout inside , Note Frame take padding 20 by default :

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10"  
       OutlineColor="Red" 
       Padding="0">
            <StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Can we increase Corner radius??

Comment: can we adjust the border width?

Comment: if you want to increase corner radius or adjust border width , you should implement custom renderer . I wrote it here :
https://gist.github.com/ads90/49cdea7d609a5b364eb34c9feedb7271

Comment: Also needs IsClippedToBounds="True" on the Frame or all the controls inside are happy to create new corners for you.

Comment: @Sonali you just need to increase the value of the property  `CornerRadius="10"` for the value that best fits for you

Comment: @NevilleNazerane the  border width is not customizable, it has a fixed value for each platform. You can "simulate" putting a frame inside another, so use the backgroundColor property and set padding on the outer until you get the appropriated appearence

Answer (score 27):

```
<!--Curved stack-->
<Frame CornerRadius="5" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalOptions="Start"
           HasShadow="True"
           IsClippedToBounds="True"
           Padding="0">
        <StackLayout Padding="10,5,10,5"   
                         Orientation="Horizontal" 
                         BackgroundColor="White"  >
            <Image Source="settingsIcon"  
                   HeightRequest="25" 
                   WidthRequest="25" 
                   Aspect="Fill" />
            <Label Text="Filter" 
                   FontSize="Medium" 
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
```

I just tried to copy BigBasket's filter buttons. [See How cool it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFuiw.png)

Comment: @sonali please check this out. . 
Thanks for asking the question.

Comment: Also you may want to IsClippedtoBounds="true" if your content bleeds.

Comment: what is BigBasket filter buttons?

Comment: I was trying to replicate the design of this component in "Bigbasket android app"

Answer (score 19):

Since Xamarin has released [Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/) mechanism, it now can be done by implementing a custom effect on both platforms. An advantage of this approach is that effects are more light-weight, reusable and can be parameterized and applied to any UI element.

After you create a custom `RoundCornersEffect` inheriting `RoutingEffect`, declare a `CornerRadius` attached property and implement `PlatformEffect` on each platform, it can be applied to any `Xamarin.Forms` layout or control like this:

```
<StackLayout effects:RoundCornersEffect.CornerRadius="48"/>
```

with hardcoded corners radius or a value from resources

```
 <BoxView effects:RoundCornersEffect.CornerRadius="{StaticResource LargeCornerRadius}" />
```

Here is a link to [full implementation and usage examples](https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/controls-and-layouts-with-rounded-corners-with-xamarin-forms-effect-f6d04444c10a).

Comment: @foxanna I love the idea and I followed your tutorial but for some reason the corners do not get rounded. I checked your instructions and my code a lot of times, same the same but in my simulator the corners do not get rounded. Everything compiles and builds fine but there is no effect.

Comment: @EmilRR1, set the breakpoints in `RoundCornersEffectIOS.OnAttached` or `RoundCornersEffectDroid.OnAttached` and make sure they are hit. Otherwise, the effect for some reason may not get attached to the view. Also, check the comment below the article, it might be useful https://medium.com/@rekerrsive/great-tutorial-anna-domashych-thanks-a5e3ab15c300.

Comment: @foxanna I figured out what the problem was. You're right those breakpoints were not hit. The reason was that I needed to add this:
**[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyAppName.MyEffectFolder")]**
It now works. Loved your tutorial thank you.

Comment: Best way to do the Job and re-usable !

Answer (score 7):

Just use a Frame with CornerRadius and set IsClippedToBounds to True. That should do the trick.

```
<Frame CornerRadius="30" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           VerticalOptions="Start"
           HasShadow="True"
           IsClippedToBounds="True"
           Padding="0">
<StackLayout></StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same need, so I created a Custom Renderer for both iOS and Android. I released it as a Nuget which you can find [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HotTotem.RoundedContentView).
The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tomh4/HotTotem.RoundedContentView), and here is a little ["How-To"](https://hot-totem.com/blog/post/plugins-hottotemroundedcontentview)

Hope this helps! 
It is very easy to use (Same as a ContentView, which it is at it's base), although note this is compile for .NET Standard, but you can also pull the code into your PCL

Answer (score 1):

A lot of valid answers were already given.

I just wanted to add that since Xamarin Forms 5, Shapes control were added.

Now, you can just add a Rectangle which exposes RadiusX and RadiusY.

Answer (score 0):

You can set rounded corner for any Layout or View or Cell (StackLayout, Grid, ListView)

http://venkyxamarin.blogspot.in/2017/12/how-to-set-corner-radius-for-view.html#more

Answer (score 0):

Try using PancakeView Nuget Package. First, install the package in your PCL project. Give the reference in xaml content page.

```
xmlns:pkView="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"

<StackLayout>
      <pkView:PancakeView>
            CornerRadius="10,0,10,0" 
      </pkView:PancakeView>
 </StackLayout>
```