# Boxview in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to design boxview within a simple page of pcl so while desgining I need to make it rounded with corners so how that actually I can achieve?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Forms: StackLayout with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186660/xamarin-forms-stacklayout-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: In the duplicate quetion you can find the solution but this solution doesn't work on UWP. If you want work on UWP you can try https://github.com/migueBarrera/Xamarin.Plugins.RoundedFrame.

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/RoundedBoxView

Comment: Purely design is  doing in C# as well so actually their is no need of  Xaml code.