# How to override the parent layout/view opacity for certain elements in xamarin forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, opacity

So I'm trying to develop a custom control which has Opacity of about 0.2, and its an entry, but the problem here is if I set the Opacity of the entry, then the Placeholder or the hint text also gets the opacity, and my custom control has an image as well, which gets the opacity as well, is there a way to override this?

I tried setting the alpha in the renderer but that doesn't seem to do the trick,

Here's my renderer and the output I need, but what I'm getting in actual

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        var element = (ImageEntry)this.Element;
        this.Control.Placeholder = element.Placeholder;            
        var textField = this.Control;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Image))
        {
            switch (element.ImageAlignment)
            {
                case ImageAlignment.Left:
                    textField.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                    textField.LeftView = GetImageView(element.Image, element.ImageHeight, element.ImageWidth);
                    break;
                case ImageAlignment.Right:
                    textField.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                    textField.RightView = GetImageView(element.Image, element.ImageHeight, element.ImageWidth);
                    break;
            }
        }
        this.Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 25;
        textField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        textField.Alpha = 1;
        CALayer bottomBorder = new CALayer
        {
            Frame = new CGRect(0.0f, element.HeightRequest - 1, this.Frame.Width, 1.0f),
            BorderWidth = 2.0f,
            BorderColor = element.LineColor.ToCGColor()
        };

        textField.Layer.AddSublayer(bottomBorder);
        textField.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
    }
```

[image: This is how i need it]

but this is what I'm getting

[image: Any Inputs would be helpful]

Comment: I do not think that you can do what you are trying to do here!

Comment: any suggestions ??

Comment: You can create a custom control that has multiple xamarin forms controls to create something like what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You can use a grid or you can use a horizontally oriented stacklayout with a background and rounded corners https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186660/xamarin-forms-stacklayout-with-rounded-corners And then just place the entry and image inside it