# Relative Layout for pictures taken from camera

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a provider for taking pictures. Its is very crucial for me that the picture has rounded corners. I have tried many plugins but the only one that seemed to work fine is pancake with in relative layout. However every time I take the picture, the picture has different size and I need the picture to be more or less the same. Is there any way that I can set the size of the picture and still be using relative layout? I am using both platforms, plus tablet and phone device so I have to handle plenty of differences. The reason I am using relative is because in no other layout the picture had rounded corners.

My Carousel view

```
<CarouselView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"  Style="{StaticResource ImageResultCarousel}" x:Name="carousel" Margin="0"
               IndicatorView="indicatorView" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageResults, Mode=TwoWay}"
                BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PictureBackground}">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <templates:ImageTamplate> </templates:ImageTamplate>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

My Template for image

```
 <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PictureBackground}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" >
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Padding="0" x:Name="layout" > 
          <yummy:PancakeView  CornerRadius="20,20,20,20">
         <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding FieldVisualData}" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PictureBackground}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0" ></Image>
         </yummy:PancakeView >
               </StackLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

My res. dictionary

My carousel view style

```
<!--ImageCarousel-->
         <Style x:Key="ImageResultCarousel"
                TargetType="StackLayout">
           <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
             <Setter.Value>
               <OnIdiom  Phone="490" Tablet="500" />
             </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
         </Style>
```

my IOS image

```
     <!--Relative iOS-->
          <Style x:Key="Relative"
            TargetType="RelativeLayout">
        <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom Phone="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,
                    Property=Width,
                    Factor=0.99}"
                         Tablet="{ConstraintExpression
                    Type=RelativeToParent,
                    Property=Width,
                    Factor=0.99}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom  Phone="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent,
                    Property=Height,
                    Factor=0.9}" Tablet="{ConstraintExpression 
                    Type=RelativeToParent,
                    Property=Height,
                    Factor=1}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom  Phone="8,0,4,0" Tablet="2"  />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
      
       

My Android Image

 <!--RelativeAndroid-->

     <Style x:Key="RelativeAndroid"
        TargetType="RelativeLayout">
    <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.XConstraint">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom Tablet="{ConstraintExpression  Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0.58,Constant=0}"
                     Phone="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=X, Factor=0.58,Constant=0}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
           <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.YConstraint">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom Tablet="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0.1, Constant=0}" 
                     Phone="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0.1, Constant=0}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
            <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint">
              <Setter.Value>
                 <OnIdiom  Phone="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.5}"
                           Tablet="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=0.2}" />
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
           <Setter Property="RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint">
              <Setter.Value>
                 <OnIdiom  Phone="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,   Factor=0.9}"
                           Tablet="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.71}" />
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
      </Style>
```

Comment: https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-how-to-clip-images-with-rounded-corners/

Comment: I have tried this, this didn't work fo me. It worked on android, but on iOS

Comment: You want picture with rounded corner? Put the image inside a Frame with corner radius. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052889/10539446).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Hua - MSFT  This doesn't work for iOS, the image is on the top of the frame

Comment: Can you please share me the code you tried? It should work.

Comment: I have tried a normal picture that worked but when I used picture from camera it didn't work. I no longer have it in my code but it was based on the example provided by Jason

Comment: What's the difference between a picture from camera and a normal picture?

Comment: the picture from camera is already somehow cropped from the provider, an honestly for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: Need some code to debug and find out the real cause.